# Get the Message notification from Nodejs REST API using Angular8 in background

Tags: node.js, angular, web-worker, angular8

I am working on an application where I want to implement the message Inbox. I have created the message inbox using Angular8 and NodeJS REST API. Now I want to get the on inbox message in every 30 Second on the background when user login also it doesn't want to affecting the performance of the Angular app.

So I want to Implement the Web-worker with Angular8 to get the Data from NodeJS REST API but I am unable to create.

I have added following code in Angular 8 App

Add this code to **app.component.ts**

```
getWorker(token){
if (typeof Worker !== 'undefined') {
  // Create a new
  const worker = new Worker('../../web-worker/messenger.worker', { type: `module` });
  worker.postMessage(token);
  worker.onmessage = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      worker.postMessage(token)
    }, 15000);
  };
} else {
  // Web Workers are not supported in this environment.
  // You should add a fallback so that your program still executes correctly.
}
```

}

Created worker file with **fetch**

```
  /// <reference lib="webworker" />

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
    const response = `worker response to ${data}`;
    postMessage(response);
  });

import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
onmessage = (message:any) => {
    fetch(environment.apiUrl +'messages/notification/1/1',
        { method:'GET',
          headers:new Headers({
            Authorization: `Bearer ${message.data}`
          })
        }
      )
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(commits => {
        // self.onmessage(message)
      return commits
    });
};
```

but it shows the **type** as fetch is should be show **web worker** Right?

[image]

> Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi, did you try calling function to fetch the message, every 30 seconds using setTimeout, if yes, does your performance got hit badly ?

Comment: No, I did not try with Fetch. I was trying with HttpClient. I will try with fetch and get back to you.

Comment: I am facing error with file not found with web-worker with Angular 8.

Comment: Is there any changes I have to do in config file ?

Comment: @HardRocker Please check I have updated the question